# How do you link to images from your docs folder in your README.rst?

Tags: python, github, restructuredtext, pypi

I'm struggling to find a way to use images in my README.rst that will show up both on github and PyPI.

Currently I'm using the following markup:

```
.. image:: https://github.com/thebjorn/pydeps/blob/master/docs/_static/pydeps.svg
```

which looks great on github (https://github.com/thebjorn/pydeps), but show up as broken links on PyPI (https://pypi.org/project/pydeps/1.6.0/).

Is this possible, or do I need to host these images somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `raw.githubusercontent.com` instead of `github.com`:

```
.. image:: https://github.com/thebjorn/pydeps/blob/master/docs/_static/pydeps-pylib.svg
```

will render correctly only on Github itself, while

```
.. image:: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thebjorn/pydeps/master/docs/_static/pydeps-pylib.svg?sanitize=true
```

will render on any website.

---

#### First attempt (broken & removed)

---

#### Second attempt:

1. replaces the URLs correctly (also removing the `blob` part in paths - my bad!),
2. appends `?sanitize=true` to each URL being replaced.

---

```
$ sed -i '' 's,.. image:: https://github.com/\(.*\)/blob/\(.*\).svg,.. image:: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/\1/\2.svg?sanitize=true,g' README.rst
```

Testing it [on Github](https://github.com/hoefling/pydeps) and [on TestPyPI](https://test.pypi.org/project/pydeps/), both looking good.

---

#### Alternative: Using [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/)

Another possibility would be using [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/), although the downside is this being a third-party service, so when it's down, the images are not rendered, although available. Nevertheless, for completeness:

```
$ sed -i '' 's,.. image:: https://github.com/\(.*\)/blob/\(.*\)$,.. image:: https://cdn.rawgit.com/\1/\2,g' README.rst
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work (it gives a broken image on github). At first I thought it was due to the content type being text/html, but I see that .png images have problems too (e.g. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/docs/_static/screen1.png)

Comment: Actually, if you remove the blob from my previous comment it works for .png files. It looks like github converts .svg files to a data url though, which .rst doesn't seem to enjoy... :-(

Comment: Got the `sed` oneliner now, please verify again.

Comment: Glad I could help!